# Notification Listener Service Android - Ionic

Tags: javascript, java, android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have developed a simple android app, but I want to move to Ionic.

I have got a problem with Notification Listener Service. When I launch the app, in the native version, it launch a notification. When I press it the app is closed.

So is it possible to do the same with ionic?

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? How do you want the notification to function? Do you mean push notification or notification inside the app?

Comment: @KrishnaKarki a push notification. I just need to start and launch a notification and when i click that one the app is closed